# Passing Authorization Bearer Token Header from login API to other page using axios

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am new to React JS. I am trying to access and pass the authorization bearer custom token from login API output to home page. How to do that using axios?

Comment: //on login page submission
 var data = {
        "data": {
        userName:this.state.userName,
        password:this.state.password,
        }
      };let axiosConfig = {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
      }; 
axios.post('/login',data, axiosConfig)
    .then((response) => {
      dispatch({type: FOUND_USER, data: response.data[1]})
  })

//session token in response.data[1]

Comment: you are dispacthed an action, its in redux state now, use reducers and get data, simple

Answer (score 0):

you can use `sessionStorage` or `localStorage`,

```
sessionStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(data));
```

you can now retrieve data using,

```
var tokenData = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('token'));
```